# Filter and replace banned words Vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

In this case, we want to filter the words in our input:

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Write something..." v-model="todoInput"">
```

These are the banned words that we want to replace from the input

> "banned", "apple", "banana",

Answer (score 0):

Here is our vue instance. The watcher replaces the banned word to asterisk (*)

```js
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: function(){
     return {
      todoInput : '',
     }
    },
    watch: {
     todoInput: function(){
      var banned = ["banned", "apple", "banana"]
      for (var i = 0; i < banned.length; i++) {
       if (this.todoInput.includes(banned[i])) {
        this.todoInput = this.todoInput.replace(banned[i], "*".repeat(banned[i].length)) //sets the input to * times the length of the banned word
       }
      }
     }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">

    <input type="text" class="form-control"
            placeholder="Write something..." 
            v-model="todoInput">

</div>
```

Comment: What about APPLE, or Apple? :)